# Pass a value from a field to skillbuilder modal, in Apex

Tags: apex

I was passing values to other page with URL button, but I changed it to open a modal with skillbuilder. How can I pass the values to the modal page?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO.  Please include some of your code so we may better help you.

Answer (score 0):

See [their tutorial](http://www.skillbuilders.com/webinars/webinar.cfm?id=53&title=Introducing%20SkillBuilders%20Modal%20Page%20Plug-in) from around 16 minutes in.  You need the button to have an attribute that holds the URL including values, then you instruct the plug-in to use that when opening the dialog.